# Deploy project without Midas.dll C++

Tags: c++, dll, c++builder, firemonkey, c++builder-xe8

I am trying to make it so I can deploy a firemonkey project which uses Midas.dll onto another machine without having to copy the DLL over as well.  [This article](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/29297) explains how to do this with a delphi project by including MidasLib in your uses clause like so:

```
program Project1;

uses
  MidasLib,
  Forms,
  Unit1 in 'Unit1.pas' {Form1};
```

I am not very familiar with delphi, but I assume that in C++ I would want to use an `#include` statement in places of the `uses` statement. Since MidasLib is a .pas file, I assume I am supposed to include `Midas.hpp`.  However, even though I include `Midas.hpp` in the file that is using it, I still get an exception saying "Midas.dll not found."

How can I deploy my project without having to copy the Midas.dll file over with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should also link the static library and call the `RegisterMidasLib` function:

```
#include <Midas.hpp>

// or use the Project Manager's "Add to Project" option
#pragma comment(lib, "midas.lib")

extern "C" __stdcall DllGetDataSnapClassObject(REFCLSID, REFIID, void **);

void InitMidas() 
{
  #pragma startup InitMidas 254
  RegisterMidasLib(DllGetDataSnapClassObject);
}
```

Further details [here](http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item.aspx?id=23881).

Comment: Additionally, I had to add `#include <DSIntf.hpp>` in order to gain access to the `RegisterMidasLib` function.